# Bartok - Syncopation (1): Meaning of notes in between Grand Staff

Tags: piano, notation, syncopation, bartok, mikrokosmos

*Bartok - Mikrokosmos Book 1 - 9<sup>1)*</sup> Syncopation(1)*

What's the meaning of the notes in between the Grand Staff?

[image: Bartok - Mikrokosmos Book 1 - 9<]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The star in the middle of the staff actually points us to a footnote given at the end of this first book. In my edition (Boosey & Hawkes), the footnote states:

> The rhythmic feeling of the suspensions should be emphasized by some energetic movement such as tapping with the foot in the places marked by rhythmic signatures between the staves.

From a pedagogical standpoint, this helps the performer place the next pitch accurately within the measure. Young musicians often speed through long held notes, so forcing a young player to think about beat 1 of the second measure will help them more successfully play beat 2.

Comment: "Young musicians often speed through long held notes" Good point. Also relevant here is the related flaw that shorter notes following longer notes can be accelerated: long waits make for impatience. Classic example: the Bb minor fugue in WTC Book 1. This gets a rant in Neuhaus' book.